# How to get new (real time) comments from my blog?

Tags: python, api, flask

I have a blog and an application that gives the number of comments and posts on my blog by using my blog's API.
The issue I'm having is that I want to have my application receive new comments from my application in real-time.

My solution:
I can have my application calling the API every 30 seconds or so to check whether there is a response (i.e. whether there is a new comment).

Comment: So what have you tried? can you show some code of your trials?

Comment: Does your blog expose a webhook? If yes, you can consume that so basically the blog will tell you when comments are updated instead of you requesting every 30s. If no, then I guess your way of doing should be good enough

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use something called Long Polling to get updates. Its a technique in programming to handle requests with less resources such as CPU being used over time. For a detailed solution for your case search for

> Long Polling in Flask application